# Biometric Facial Recognition Command Line Tool

Tags: performance, command-line, comparison, face-recognition, biometrics

I would like to perform a simple task: to upload a client image to the server and compare this image with other images in a folder. To do so I could use a command line tool compiled in a low or mid-level language (such as C) and call the binary via php. Does anyone know any software/library on that model?

Comment: Sorry, but requests for recommendations are off-topic on StackOverflow. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/tour , http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask , and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . Good luck.

Comment: Alright. Thankyou.

Comment: You are asking an off-topic question (software shopping). Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic. See [On Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Try https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/  but please first read [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"](https://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).